# Why class.dex file is different when build the same source code

Tags: android, compiler-construction, dex

I built same android project by Eclipse + Android plugin on same machine 5 times.
The 1st build's class.dex file and the 3rd build's class.dex file are the same but they're different than the other build.
Although i think class.dex file should be the same but i don't know much about Android compiler process. I wonder if this is about compiler's multi-thread or optimization process.
Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you check it to be the same or not?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i extracted apk file as a zip file and diff the content by WinMerge.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways a dex file can be bytewise-different from another, and yet be semantically identical.

For example, in some sections in the dex file, the order of items is not specified, so the item can be placed in different locations in 2 different, but semantically equivalent dex files.